# simple cheap delay start relay?

Tags: timer, delay

What is the cheapest, simplest component or device that once receives power will wait approx. 1 second before outputting that power, like a delay relay.

It can be any small DC voltage as it will power a another 240 solid state relay, I just need that one sec delay? Can any single component achieve this?

Comment: That is a very common industrial component called a "time delay relay".  Industrial and "cheap" do not necessarily go hand-in-hand though some Asian devices are quite inexpensive.

Comment: Incidentally the surge when your compressor comes on could be more than 1 second long.  Ideally you should start the second compressor when the first has reached steady load.

Comment: Yeah, what KH says, use a current relay to detect when the compressor has started.

Comment: Regarding your deleted non-answer and your abusive comments you should take the [Tour] to learn how SE sites work and why your non-answer was inappropriate and why it was deleted. Some of the content belonged as an update to your question - not as an answer. That's how the site works and the downvotes reflect that. Being rude to those who give freely of their time to help you is not a good strategy.

Comment: where the hell was I being abusive ??? I was clearly greatful for all or any comments I always am even if I dont agree Im never abusive. WTF I dont get it? Please tell me what did I say then.. I just Thanked the members for there input, especially Seikku who took the time to explain a component setup for me even tho its over my head, so tell me  where was I ever abusive?

Comment: Oh, you mean where I was annoyed with moderator for deleteing the comments where I thanked the people who help me? Whatever dude your clearly more powerful than I. Ill just get on with my medial life then. Bye!

Comment: To quote: "you people are retarded. Get a life." Your comments above are abusive too so you might want to reconsider your "abusive" standards and what is considered acceptable in polite society. The moderators (and I'm not one) also give freely of their time to keep the site running well. You broke the rules so it had to be addressed. Bye.

Comment: sorry buttercup I apologise

Answer (score 0):

Try your favorite china supplier and look for an on delay relay, they are only a few bucks, some are fixed some are adjustable. Normally open, on-delay timers start timing when the input voltage (power) is applied. The output is energized at the end of the delay. Input voltage has to be removed to de-energize the output and reset the time delay relay. You can use google and try searching for "on delay relay" and click on shopping to find them for sale.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for *about* 1 second on-delay, how about an RC delay? The input of a DC-driven SSR is a LED with about 1 kilo-ohm resistor in series. It should go "on" at less than 3 volts. If you charge a 10'000 µF capacitor through a 100 ohm resistor from 5V, you reach 3 volts at about 1 second. Driving from higher voltage would need a higher resistance.